# Multiselect Element color change

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to apply **styles** on elements in kendo multiselect according to my inline style given in an Array Text Field.

TS File

```
dataValues: Array<{value: number, text: string}> = [{value: 1, text: "<span style='color:red'>value 1</span>"},{value: 2, text: "value 2"}, {value: 3, text: "<span style='color:red'>value 3</span>"}]
```

HTML File

```
<kendo-multiselect 
      [checkboxes]="true" 
      [autoClose]="false"
      [data]="dataValues"
      [textField]="'text'"
      [valueField]="'value'"
      [valuePrimitive]="true">
</kendo-multiselect>
```

Output

[image]

Output should be like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [templates](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/templates/) to format the values. And you has two options

1. Inject domSanitizer and use innerHTML in template

   ```
     constructor(private domSanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

    public listItems: Array<value: number,text:SafeStyle>=[
         {value:1,text:this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
           '<span style="color:red">Value 1</span>')},
         {value:2,text:this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
           '<span style="color:green">Value 2</span>')},
         ...]

   <div class="example-wrapper">
           <kendo-label text="T-shirt size:">
             <kendo-multiselect
               [checkboxes]="true"
               [autoClose]="false"
               [data]="listItems"
               [(ngModel)]='value'
               textField="text"
               valueField="value"
             >
               <ng-template kendoMultiSelectItemTemplate let-dataItem>
                 <div [innerHTML]="dataItem.text"></div>
               </ng-template>
             </kendo-multiselect>
           </kendo-label>
         </div>
   ```
2. Use a new property, e.g. color and use some like

   ```
   public listItems: Array<{ text: string, value: number,color?:any}> = [
       { text: 'Small', value: 1,color:'red'},
       { text: 'Medium', value: 2 },
       { text: 'Large', value: 3,color:'green' }
   ];

   <div class="example-wrapper">
       <kendo-label text="T-shirt size:">
         <kendo-multiselect
           [checkboxes]="true"
           [autoClose]="false"
           [data]="listItems"
           [(ngModel)]='value'
           textField="text"
           valueField="value"
         >
           <ng-template kendoMultiSelectItemTemplate let-dataItem>
             <span [style.color]="dataItem.color">{{dataItem.text}}</span>
           </ng-template>
         </kendo-multiselect>
       </kendo-label>
     </div>
   ```